# Java JSoup library element.text() returns '&nbsp;' as a #160 ASCII character

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I just recently bumped into a strange behavior of **JSoup library 1.3.3** (quite old, I know).

When parsing text node, and this conatins `&nbsp;` entity it is **converted** by calling .text() on this element to **#160 ASCII char**.

Have you experienced this? Do you think this is a correct behavior? *(checked Jsoup repo for error, none found)*

Thanks,

Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-breaking space is *not* the same as a normal space. Non breaking space is 0xA0 or 160 decimal in ISO-8859-*, Windows-1252, it is U+00A0 in Unicode (in UTF-8 it is encoded to 0xC2 0xA0). So depending on your exact encoding this is correct behaviour.